# An example in sheaf generated by global sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is an example from Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry (II, 7.6.3):

Let $X$ be the nonsingular cubic curve $y^{2}z=x^{3}-xz^{2}$ in $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ (it is not a rational curve). Let $\mathscr{L}$ be the invertible sheaf of divisor $P_{0}$, where $P_{0}$ is the point $(0,1,0)$ and the line $z=0$ meets the curve at the divisor $3P_{0}$.

It says that "this $\mathscr{L}$ is not generated by global sections because it it were, then $P_{0}$ will be linearly equivalent to some other point $Q \in X$". Why is this true?

Suppose $\mathscr{L}$ is generated by $s_{i}$'s, if I choose a sheaf $\mathscr{K}$ generated by $s_{i}^{-1}$. Then $\mathscr{LK}$ is principal, but it is not necessary the associated sheaf of a single point.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The sheaf has one section, namely the constant function 1. This does  not generate it, so if it is globally generated, it must have another rational function $f$ (non-constant) in it. But, then $f$ must have only one pole of order one at $P_0$, so it must have a zero of order one. (Remember $mathrm{div} f$ has degree zero. This says, $P_0$ is equivalent to $Q$, the zero of $f$.